# Predicting Different Classes by the Size of Test data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I don't know why `tf.estimator.predict` predicts difference classes by size of `test_data`.

```
test_data = list()
for i in range(8, 10):
    test_data.append(mpimg.imread(FLAGS.input + 'test-' + str(i) + '.png'))
test_data = np.asarray(test_data)
test_data = test_data[:, :, :, :3].astype(np.float32)

...
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=custom_model_fn, model_dir=FLAGS.modelPath)
pred_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = { 'x': test_data }, shuffle = False, num_epochs = 1)
```

By above code, the `test_data` consists of `test-8.png` and `test-9.png` that have each labels for `8` and `9`.

Through the prediction of the model, the `test_data` infers each labels for `3` and `9`.

But when I use test_data of size 3,

```
for i in range(7, 10):
    test_data.append(mpimg.imread(FLAGS.input + 'test-' + str(i) + '.png'))
```

the `test_data` extends its size to 3 and consists of `test-7.png` and `test-8.png` and `test-9.png` the have each labels for `7`, `8` and `9`.

But `test_data` infers each labels for `7`, `8` and `9`.

I wonder why the expected class of `test-8.png` is different in the first and second code.
Also, I can not understand why the size of `test_data` affects the actual prediction.

Perhaps there is an error in the code, and I would appreciate to you if you can tell my what error it has.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   import argparse
   import scipy.io
   import matplotlib.image as mpimg
   tf.estimator.RunConfig(
       ...
   )

   if FLAGS.isTrain:
      mat_data = scipy.io.loadmat(FLAGS.inputMat)
      data = mat_data['X']
      labels = mat_data['y']
      data = data.reshape(data.shape[0] * data.shape[1] * data.shape[2], data.shape[3]).T
      data = data/np.float32(255)
      labels = labels.reshape(labels.shape[0]) % 10

      train_data = data[:500000]
      train_labels = make_onehot_vector(labels[:500000].astype(np.float32))

      ...

      classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(custom_model_fn, model_dir = FLAGS.modelPath)
      tensors_to_log = {"probabilities" : "softmax_tensor"}
      logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=2000)

      train_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn( x = {"x":train_data}, y = train_labels, batch_size = FLAGS.batch_size, num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epoch, shuffle = True)
      train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSepc(input_fn=train_input, max_stpes=FLAGS.num_stpes)

      ...

      tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
      classifier.export_savedmodel(FLAGS.modelPath, serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)


    else:
      test_data = list()
      for i in range(8, 10):
          test_data.append(mpimg.imread(FLAGS.input + 'test-' + str(i) + '.png'))
      test_data = np.asarray(test_data)
      test_data = test_data[:, :, :, :3].astype(np.float32)
      test_data = test_data.reshape(-1, 32*32*3)

      classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = custom_model_fn, model_dir = FLAGS.modelPath)
      pred_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x = {"x": test_Data}, y = None, shuffle=False, num_epochs = 1)
      pred_result = classifier.predict(input_fn = pred_input)
      pred_list = list(pred_result)
      print(pred_list)
```

```
def custom_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features['x'], [-1, 32, 32, 3])
    isTrain = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    L1 = cnn(input_layer, 32, [5,5], [2,2], 2, phase=isTrain)
    ...
    L5 = cnn(L4, 196, [5,5], [2,2], 2, phase=isTrain)

    L5_flat = tf.reshape(L5, [-1, 196 * 3 * 3])
    L6 = dense_batch_relu(L5_flat, isTrain, 1024, 'L6')
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=L6, units = 10, activation=None)
    predictions = {"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1), "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")}

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        export_outputs = {"predict_output": tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, export_outputs=export_outputs)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)) + tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

    if mode == tf.estimator ModeKeys.TRAIN:
       optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(5e-4)
       train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step = tf.train.get_global_step())
       return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

    Y = tf.argmax(labels, 1)
    eval_metric_ops = {"acc" : tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=Y, predictions=predictions['classes'])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    inputs = {
        'x':tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32*32*3]),
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)
```

In this code, why is the smaller the test data, the more inaccurate the predicted value and the larger the size, the more accurate the predicted value?

Comment: Why do train_data slices start to 50k and train_labels slices 50k to rest?

Comment: you're right, I made mistakes to type my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `tf.layers.batch_normalization` in `dense_batch_relu`

```
def dense_batch_relu(x, phase, unit, scope, dropout_rate=0.3):
   with tf.variable_scope(scope):
      reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale = 5e-3)
      l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, unit, activation = None, kernel_regularizer=reg)
      l2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=l1, training=phase)
      l3 = tf.layers.dropout(l2, dropout_rate, training=phase)

      return tf.nn.relu(l3, 'relu')
```

But, I had not added `tf.conrol_dependencies` in `tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN`

so, I modified the code into below:

```
if mode == tf.estimator ModeKeys.TRAIN:
   update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
   with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
       optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(5e-4)
       train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step = tf.train.get_global_step())
       return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

Then, It performs well.